# How to wrap text in LaTeX tables?

Tags: text, latex, word-wrap

I am creating a report using LaTeX, however, the cell data in the table is exceeding the width of the page.

How can I wrap the text so that it falls into the next line within the same cell of the table?

Is the solution somehow related to specifying the table's width? As the table is exceeding the page's width, would specifying the table's width make a difference?

Comment: I was looking for a way to wrap long word, the other solution better suits my needs tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198325/wrap-word-in-table-cell

Answer (score 777, accepted):

Use p{width} for your column specifiers instead of l/r/c.

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{3cm}|}
  This text will be wrapped & Some more text \\
\end{tabular}
```

---

EDIT: (based on the comments)

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.35\linewidth} | p{0.6\linewidth}}
      Column 1  & Column2 \\ \hline
      This text will be wrapped & Some more text \\
      Some text here & This text maybe wrapped here if its tooooo long \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

we get:

[image]

Comment: Good solution, but lose the '|' if you don't want a border around the table. It would then become `\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{3cm}}`

Comment: Is there any way to do this while still specifying alignment in each cell?

Comment: I found a way to specify alignment in each cell! Create a macro! \newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.8cm}}

\begin{table*}[t]
%\small
\caption{Comparison}
\centering

%\begin{tabular}{|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|}

Comment: What if I have two columns where the first should be as long as needed to fit it's contents and the other should fill to the line width, while wrapping? So basically, I need `begin{tabular}{lp{<whatever is left to fill the line width>}}`

Comment: Great solution. However, I'd recommend using relative values instead of arbitrary dimension, e.g. `p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.6\linewidth}}`

Comment: Specifying the width manually is clearly a major flaw with this method (who *really* wants to specify the width, just because they want the text to wrap?) I'd suggest using `tabularx` as suggested by @DamienPollet

Comment: @Veridian I get error just by ditto copying and pasting your macro before the beginning of the document. I am sure you meant otherwise. Could you kindly elaborate on which part needs to be copied where?

Comment: What does p stand for?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if the table has multi-columns:( Am I right? In my case, the table has lengthy column headings but it doesn't wrap. Please guide me.

Comment: I am getting error "! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.197 \end{tabular} }"

Comment: Good solution. But it is not working in case of multirow{}. What would be the solution then?

Comment: @ashman **p** is for _paragraph_ :)

Comment: How would you then center these paragraphs within their respective cells like ```c``` would do?

Comment: how to maintain center alignment additionally?

Answer (score 167):

With the regular `tabular` environment, you want to use the `p{width}` column type, as marcog indicates. But that forces you to give explicit widths.

Another solution is the `tabularx` environment:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
...
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ r X }
    right-aligned foo & long long line of blah blah that will wrap when the table fills the column width\\
\end{tabularx}
```

---

All X columns get the same width. You can influence this by setting `\hsize` in the format declaration:

```
>{\setlength\hsize{.5\hsize}} X >{\setlength\hsize{1.5\hsize}} X
```

but then all the factors have to sum up to 1, I suppose (I took this from the LaTeX companion). There is also the package `tabulary` which will adjust column widths to balance row heights. For the details, you can get the documentation for each package with `texdoc tabulary` (in TeXlive).

Comment: Interesting, that looks really useful. How intelligent is it when it comes to selecting column widths? For example, if you have two columns that need to be wrapped but one with much longer text than the other, does it still asign them equal width?

Comment: I edited my answer. But actually in practice I try simplify my tables so that I only need X for a single column. I just discovered tabulary :)

Answer (score 63):

Another option is to insert a minipage in each cell where text wrapping is desired, e.g.:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{l}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\columnwidth}%
a very long line a very long line a very long line a very long line
a very long line a very long line a very long line a very long line
a very long line a very long line a very long line %
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to place `itemize` lists in my cells.

Comment: I think the answer should explain the meaning of `\columnwidth`: When I tried it, it seemed to be more table-width rather than column-width, so I had to set a manual proportion like `0.2\columnwidth` to get a reasonable width.

Answer (score 51):

I like the simplicity of `tabulary` package:

```
\usepackage{tabulary}
...
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LCL}
    \hline
    Short sentences      & \#  & Long sentences                                                 \\
    \hline
    This is short.       & 173 & This is much loooooooonger, because there are many more words.  \\
    This is not shorter. & 317 & This is still loooooooonger, because there are many more words. \\
    \hline
\end{tabulary}
```

In the example, you arrange the whole width of the table with respect to \textwidth. E.g 0.4 of it. Then the rest is automatically done by the package.

Most of the example is taken from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables .

Comment: Any idea why this would't work for me?

Answer (score 49):

Simple like a piece of CAKE!

You can define a new column type like (`L` in this case) while **maintaining the current alignment** (`c`, `r` or `l`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|L|L|}
        \hline
        Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 \\
        \hline 
        one-liner & multi-line and centered & \multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}|}{multi-line piece of text to show case a multi-line and justified cell}   \\
        \hline
        apple & orange & banana \\
        \hline
        apple & orange & banana \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how do you make the text in the 'multi-line piece ...' center align

Comment: @Jung notice having `L` in the corresponding column `\begin{tabular}{|c|L|L|}`

Answer (score 7):

If you want to wrap your text but maintain alignment then you can wrap that cell in a `minipage` or `varwidth` environment (varwidth comes from the varwidth package). Varwidth will be "as wide as it's contents but no wider than X". You can create a custom column type which acts like "p{xx}" but shrinks to fit by using

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\begin{varwidth}[t]{#1}}l<{\end{varwidth}}}
```

which may require the `array` package. Then when you use something like `\begin{tabular}{llM{2in}}` the first two columns we be normal left-aligned and the third column will be normal left aligned but if it gets wider than 2in then the text will be wrapped.

Answer (score 7):

To change the text `AB` into `A \r B` in a table cell, put this into the cell position: `\makecell{A \\ B}`.

Before doing that, you also need to include package `makecell`.

Comment: This makes the content centered by default, you can define alignment by ```\makecell[l]{A \\ B}``` (l = left, r=right)

Answer (score 4):

The new `tabularray` makes wrapping text in cells easier then ever before.

The package supports all the traditional used column names like `c`, `l`, `r`, etc., but also has its own `Q` column which accepts various keys to control the width and vertical and horizontal alignment. It also provides an `X` column, as known from tabularx` which will automatically calculate the width of the column to fit the table into the available text width.

Another nice feature is that all the settings can also be done for individual cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tblr}{|c|Q[2cm,valign=m]|X[j,valign=m]|}
        \hline
        Title 1 & Title 2 & Title 3 \\
        \hline 
        one-liner & multi-line text & multi-line piece of text to show case a multi-line and justified cell   \\
        \hline
        apple & orange & banana \\
        \hline
        \SetCell{h,2cm} wrapping text only in a single cell & orange & banana \\
        \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(thanks to [Shayan Amani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53857840/2777074) for providing a MWE in their answer!)

Comment: it is a really useful package, thank you!

Answer (score -18):

```
\begin{table}
 \caption{ Example of force text wrap}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
   \hline
   cell 1       &   cell 2 \\   \hline
   cell 3                &       cell 4 & & very big line that needs to be wrap. \\ \hline
   cell 5       &   cell 6 \\   \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{table:example}
 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Downvote. This is a code-only answer, with no explanation at all.

Comment: Furthermore, it is wrong anyway since the second row contains 4 cells where the table is designed to accommodate only two columns. And it is not related to wrapping cell content anyhow.